# Polymorphic subclass incorrectly queries STI sublass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, polymorphism

I have an STI subclass, SoftCredits::EventBrite < SoftCredit, that has a function called on creation of SoftCredit

```
def create_activity
  options = {
     owner: person,
     created_at: additional_data['created_at'],
     updated_at: additional_data['updated_at'],
     trail_item_type: "Activities::EventBriteRegistration",
     trail_item_id: self.id
   }
  Activity.create(options)
end
```

Activity model is polymorphic

```
belongs_to :trail_item, :polymorphic => true
```

The Activities::EventBriteRegistration model declaration looks like so:

```
class Activities::EventBriteRegistration < SoftCredit
  def self.default_scope
    unscoped
  end
end
```

My issue is when I have an Activity type of Activities::EventBriteRegistration and I query on it event_brite_registration_activity.trail_item, the query is construct like so:

```
SELECT "soft_credits".* FROM "soft_credits" WHERE "soft_credits"."type" IN ('Activities::EventBriteRegistration') AND "soft_credits"."id" =[id] LIMIT 1.
```

Of course, there is no type Activities::EventBriteRegistration for SoftCredits and I am confused how I should construct this so when I do event_brite_registration_activity.trail_item, it queries on SoftCredit to find the correct soft credit.